# Connection sharing in JCA glassfish

Tags: glassfish, connection, sharing, jca

I have a misunderstanding regarding the connection handle sharing in JCA.

I want to know if the connection sharing only happens during a phase of transaction ( multiple components call ) or the connection sharing is possible amongst multiple clients accessing a component that has the same EIS destination.

I created my own resource adapter on Glassfish application server 3.1. The problem is the resource adapter doesn't perform any connection sharing (no associateConnection method call).

Thanks,